# Removing footer only for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using Bootstrap 3 to code a 3-4 page website for work. Is there a way to make it so that  the footer doesn't show when someone visits the website on a mobile device? I still want it to show on the desktop version of the website site.

Comment: You could use bootstrap media queries to do that.

Comment: Media queries? http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 4):

The Bootstrap 3 Responsive utilities support this use case by adding a class to your footer. You want might something like the `.visible-lg` or `.hidden-xs` class on the footer. You can see the full list of test cases on http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

The example that has `class="visible-md visible-lg"` is probably the one you want.

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS media queries, something like:

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    #footer {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the above CSS classes?

```
.hidden-xs /* phone */ 
.hidden-sm /* phablet/tablet */
```

you may use them together:

```
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">...</div>
```

Comment: amazing.   this hides my jacked up .css when a phone distorts it.  thanks.

Comment: Do you know how it is for Bootstrap 4?